# A suggestion to improve 'similar questions' suggestions: let's include tags.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, asking-questions

Sorry for the title.

When I write a new question, right below the title, a drop-down menu opens up with suggestions of questions similar to mine.

My suggestion is to interact that menu with the tag system, in a way that only questions with at least one of my tags shows up.

Now, any question, as long as it has the same words, even if in completely different areas, shows up and clogs the drop-down menu.

Comment: This strikes me as having a bit of cart-before-horse problem in that tags are not the first step for many who write Questions, so the related Questions suggestions begin with the title formulation.  It might be difficult for first time askers to know what the best tags are for a given Question.  Of course experienced users are expected to do [a better job of searching before asking](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and [tags are easily included in a search formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: Problem is many things can be restated. Goldbach's conjecture has at least 10 conditions on p or q . Grimms has a statement on prime gaps, as does legendre. Any solution to Beals jas conditions. Twin prime conjecture, can be made into a Goldbach partition statement, or one on natural numbers in general. etc. been a few threads in meta on abstract duplicates.

Comment: @hardmath I'm just proposing for the possibility, not for an enforcement. For those who, when asking, already know the tags, it would facilitate much, instead of just searching by ourselves in another tab...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee yes they can be restated, but they would have the same tags. I'm just suggesting this would curb the growth of repeated questions.

Comment: they need not to is my point.

Comment: My impression is that tags are used to select similar questions, see the posts on network-wide meta: [Would it be feasible to tie the tags of a new question to the Related Questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27566#91575) and [Feedback requested: Similar Questions displayed in sidebar on /ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91568). I left a few more comments [in Math Meta Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64952/2019/7/14).

Comment: So I stand corrected - I was told in chat by more experienced users that the information in the posts I've linked is outdated. Not too long ago there was made this post about A-B testing of a new version of similar questions list on Meta Stack Overflow: [Duplicate questions display experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384710). The [most upvoted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384710/duplicate-questions-display-experiment/384716#384716) is the suggestion to include tags into the criteria - so you're in favor of this, you might upvote that post.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks ;)